# couchbase n1ql update gives error 3000 when updating

Tags: nosql, couchbase, sql++

I have a couchbase document with this structure stored in a bucket named dev_hostels:

```
{
  "updatedAt": "2019-12-24T12:30:07.175Z",
  "data": {
    "type": {
      "value": "n/a"
    }
  }
}
```

The n1ql update query

```
UPDATE `dev_hostels` set data.type.value = "GUEST_HOUSE", updatedAt = NOW_MILLIS() where meta().id  = "HOSTEL:1";
```

or

```
UPDATE `dev_hostels` USE KEYS "HOSTEL:1" SET  data.type.value = "GUEST_HOUSE", updatedAt = NOW_MILLIS()  RETURNING meta().id;
```

but I got this error

```
 "code": 3000,
    "msg": "syntax error - at value",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**value** is a keyword, so you have to use escape it with backticks as well

```
UPDATE `dev_hostels` set data.type.`value` = "GUEST_HOUSE", updatedAt = NOW_MILLIS() where meta().id  = "HOSTEL:1";
```